# How to read TextBox foreground/background property in XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, ivalueconverter

I have a TextBox and like to set the foreground and background with a converter. Setting the values by the converter in general is no problem. But if nothing should be converted under some circumstances I'd like the converter to return the brush from the TextBox itself so that nothing is changed (converted). Idea is here to pass the controls brush as ConverterParameter to the converter.

How can I read the foreground/background property in XAML that comes from the style?
Is there a better approach to convert the background/foreground than using a converter?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you are on the right track with the converter.

Why dont you just have the converter return the same brush, the textbox is using? Rather than getting the brush from the textbox, simply return the brush you need.  Wouldnt this solve your problem?

Comment: That's what I do at the moment. But i thought it would be nicer to have the style's brush returned. Otherwise if the style changes for whatever reason my converter will return the wrong brush. Maybe it's easier to use an AttachedBehavior here. At least here I know how to get the brush from the style in the ViewModel to use it as default.